# UICollectionView cell is not getting added as a subview of UICollectionView

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uicollectionview, uicollectionviewcell

I am new to `UICollectionView`.

I have followed [this tutorial](http://www.appcoda.com/ios-programming-uicollectionview-tutorial/) to learn how to use a `UICollectionView`, but the problem is that in the `.xib` (not using storyboard) I am not able to add `UICollectionViewCell` as a subview of `UICollectionView`.

In the tutorial the cell is automatically created under `UICollectionView` in the `.xib`.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: What did you try to add UICollectionViewCell as a subview?

Comment: We need your code please, We can't guess what's going on.

Comment: Otherwise how can I add elements ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That tutorial is for working in stroy board in xib you ve to create custom cell first create view controller add UicollectionView to view Controller

[image]
[image]

then create custom class for collection cell

[image]

then craete empty xib resource and add collection view cell
 [image]
[image]
[image]

and set class name and identifier for that control 
[image]

then create delegates method to add custom cell to ur collectionViewController

```
-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"customCell";

    customCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    return cell;

}
```

Comment: :thank you for your reply.But afetr using ur code code app gets crashed with error *** Assertion failure in -[UICollectionView _dequeueReusableViewOfKind:withIdentifier:forIndexPath:]   I solved it by using the code [self.CollectionView registerClass:[PeopleHub class] forCellWithReuseIdentifier:@"Cell"] in viewDidload.but after that also i amgetting the null value for image used in the cell     PeopleHub *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSLog(@"cell image %@ ",cell.imgAvatar);..

Comment: Thank you Yohan.Fixed the issue by replacing[self.cv registerClass ....] with [self.cv registerNib ....]

Comment: thats great happy coding!!

Answer (score 0):

You can start your controller and create a custom collection view cell for setting your view element and then you can use it into your collection view controller into xib, here is a good tutorials to do this http://adoptioncurve.net/archives/2012/09/a-simple-uicollectionview-tutorial/

Answer (score 0):

Use this code for creation of collectionview and adding the subview.

```
-(NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInCollectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView {

    return [imageArray count];
}

-(NSInteger)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView numberOfItemsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    NSMutableArray *sectionArray = [imageArray objectAtIndex:section];
    return [sectionArray count];

}

-(UICollectionViewCell *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView cellForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    // Setup cell identifier
    static NSString *cellIdentifier = @"cvCell";

    /*  Uncomment this block to use nib-based cells */
    // UICollectionViewCell *cell = [collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    // UILabel *titleLabel = (UILabel *)[cell viewWithTag:100];
    // [titleLabel setText:cellData];
    /* end of nib-based cell block */

    /* Uncomment this block to use subclass-based cells */
    CVCell *cell = (CVCell *)[collectionView dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:cellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];
    NSMutableArray *data = [imageArray objectAtIndex:indexPath.section];
    NSString *cellData = [data objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    [cell.titleLabel setText:cellData];

    cell.imageView.image = [UIImage imageNamed:[imageArray[indexPath.section] objectAtIndex:indexPath.row]];

    return cell;

}
- (UICollectionReusableView *)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView viewForSupplementaryElementOfKind:(NSString *)kind atIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    header *sectionHeader;
    if (kind == UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader)
    {
        sectionHeader = [collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"Hello" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    }
    UICollectionReusableView *test=[collectionView dequeueReusableSupplementaryViewOfKind:UICollectionElementKindSectionHeader withReuseIdentifier:@"Hello" forIndexPath:indexPath];
    return test;

}
- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout referenceSizeForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    if (section == 3) {
        return CGSizeMake(0, 100);
    }

    return CGSizeZero;
}


- (NSString *)applicationDocumentsDirectory {
    return [NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) lastObject];
}


- (CGSize)collectionView:(UICollectionView *)collectionView layout:(UICollectionViewLayout*)collectionViewLayout sizeForItemAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    return CGSizeMake(80, 80);
}
```